# Recommendations for C# database access

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-connection

Hi I've programmed a fair bit of C#, but never with a database. I'd like to use SQL Server with C# with some framework. Microsoft seems to have shipped a number of frameworks through the lifetime of C#. This makes it difficult for me to search/choose.

Which one should I choose? I'm developing a simple 3-tier webapp. I've watched a few Entity Framework .Net 4.0 videos, but I get the feeling that things are too automatic. I need to do some SQL now and then..

And if I should go for the EF4.0, is this really the best reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Any recommendations?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/12/18/my-christmas-present-to-the-entity-framework-community.aspx   looks like a great free pdf book on EF

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go with **Entity Framework 4** - it is the current and future best approach to SQL Server database. It is the basis for WCF Data Services, and the idea of a conceptual model will show up in other Microsoft product, for sure (Reporting Services and others, possibly).

And it does give you a lot of hooks to allow you to execute "on the fly" SQL statements, and you can also integrate stored procedures very nicely into Entity Framework.

And for the "run of the mill" everyday tasks, it gives you nice C# objects - based on your database - to work with.

In my opinion, this is your best choice currently - and the one with the most flexibility and options. You can start with a database ("database first") and create your classes from existing tables; or you can start with a model and have EF4 generate your database for you, and EF v4.1 (due out pretty soon) will also offer "code-first" development where you don't even need a visual model but you can describe all your database objects and settings in just C# code.

**Update:**

- [Entity Framework 4 Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx)
- [Learn Entity Framework](http://learnentityframework.com/learnentityframework/) - the site accompanying the book by the same name, by Julie Lerman, Goddess of EF :-)
- [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) with lots of good EF stuff
- [Entity Framework team design blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/)
- [ASP.NET 4.0 and the Entity Framework 4 - Part 1 - Create a Database using Model-First Development](http://aspalliance.com/1912_ASPNET_40_and_the_Entity_Framework_4__Part_1__Create_a_Database_using_ModelFirst_Development) - good intro for EF4 model-first approach; Vince has multiple articles here - click on his name to get a list of all his articles (many new ones EF4 related)
- [Introduction to Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/IntroEntityFramework3.aspx) (this was for v1 - but still good)

Answer (score 2):

I would say Start with Rob Conery's Sub Sonic..
Its easy to start with..specillaly Simple Repository..

Site Link:  http://www.subsonicproject.com/

Simple Repository using Sub Sonic:
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Repo_5_Minute_Demo

Update:
I have seen one answer mentioning NHibernate and want to add a small addition to the same... and since OP mentinoned that you have good experience with C# I assume you have good OOPS knowledge and also the relationships amongs objects

I personally felt much easy to start with NHibernate when used it with Fluent NHibernate hence I would also suggest

C# + NHibernate + Fluent Nhibernate....

Comment: yeah http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Repo_5_Minute_Demo looks slick... but I always get suspicious when the examples/videos show simple insert/delete/fetch. What happened to joins and where-clauses? maybe even a nested select?

Comment: The video on the site is a good one to start with and I think there are lot of resources online which can help one move ahead with more joins etc...

Answer (score 2):

C#+ActiveRecord+NHibernate. Hide the implementation behind several WCF services.

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to try some 'framework', so Entity Framework is that one. It is the result from best practices MS come up with after years of research. Of course, on the way, you can always use SQL (Dataset) anytime you want together with EF (mostly for performance tuning).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://ormeter.net/) for some information about performance/benchmarks on various ORM frameworks for .Net.